# How to give access to a route in Vue.js only througth router link

Tags: javascript, vue.js, router

I have the route **/myPath** in my Vue.js application. I want it to be accesible only througth a router-link. Else, if an user tries to access directly he will be redirected to "not found" page.

Is this possible with Vue.js router features/functionalities?

Comment: Enable [history mode](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html) and it might work, but mind you its not a a feature but a side effect.

Comment: This is a weird way to do any access related restrictions, but to answer your question: you can control a route with [navigation guards](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can check the route user is trying to navigate from using [Navigation Guards](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#global-before-guards). Something like this, for example:

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
    if (from === "route_with_the_router_link") {
        next()
    } else {
        next(false)
    }
})
```